# How to setup HTTP check for TCP backend in HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

The documentation suggests that I can setup a HTTP check for a TCP backend.

The liveness of my backend is determined by a `405 Method Not allowed` response when hitting `a-app.com/ap_service`

My config looks like this:

```
frontend app-api
    bind *:443
    mode tcp

    option tcplog
    default_backend app-api_backend


backend app-api_backend
    mode tcp
    option httpchk GET /app_service HTTP/1.1
    http-check expect status 405
    server a a-app.com:443  resolvers dns verify none inter 1000  check
    server b b-app.com:443  resolvers dns verify none inter 1000  check
```

However, in the logs I get:

```
Server app-api_backend/a is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, check duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Server app-api_backend/b is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, check duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
...
```

Comment: So, I understand that your HAProxy Health Checks failing due to error 405 Method Not Allowed. Not sure if this is already the reason: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/126, https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/64.

Comment: not sure if i have understand correctly. here seems that every backend alive condition is a 405 response. server b  reply 405 so it looks up while server a doesn't so it marked as down.

Comment: djv, actually I get the same logs for both backends. When I copy and pasted it didn't add the line for server `b`. And just to confirm `405` is my expected response for my health check.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that you expect haproxy to make HTTPS requests guessing that port 443 is served on it, while `option httpchk` does only plain HTTP requests.

Serve your app over plain HTTP on a different port, apart from HTTPS, make it available for haproxy node, and use HTTP for the checks.

See example in [haproxy option httpchk](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxydconv/1.8/configuration.html#option%20httpchk) docs:

```
    # Relay HTTPS traffic to Apache instance and check service availability
    # using HTTP request "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1" on port 80.
    backend https_relay
        mode tcp
        option httpchk OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www
        server apache1 192.168.1.1:443 check port 80
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
    backend app-api_backend
        mode tcp
        option httpchk GET /app_service HTTP/1.1
        http-check expect status 405
        server a a-app.com:443  resolvers dns verify none inter 1000 check port 80
        server b b-app.com:443  resolvers dns verify none inter 1000 check port 80
```